# Ledger larger than house rim joist

Tags: deck

I want to attach a 2x12 ledger to my house, but looking at the rim joist of the house it seems to be a 2x10 sitting on two 2x sill plates.

Is it a problem attaching the 2x12 ledger to the 2x10 house rim joist?

Comment: The size doesn't matter but the exchange from your house does.

Answer (score 1):

No problem doing this. Make sure that you attach it in an appropriate manner. The preferred approach is to use a special deck tie (Simpson makes them) that uses a thick rod to connect a deck joist to a house joist. If that's not practical, using lag bolts in an alternating pattern. Most permitting authorities have specific guidance on what they want to see here.

Comment: By code you need both.  2 tension bolts are required.  Its been code for awhile but inspectors in my area are now requiring it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an engineer, but it should be no problem.  Be sure to lag screw or thru bolt it to the rim.  Do not use nails except as a temporary hold up.  Use joint hangers on the ledger... these are often easier to install before it goes on the wall.

Also ensure you flash the top of it with Z flashing tucked up under the siding and over the ledger.  You don't want water getting behind the ledger and rotting out the connection.